# Why isin't expo go working on my mobile device?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using expo-cli in react native, and I'm running it on my phisical Android phone (LG M151) using Expo Go. At first, after scanning, my app worked normally, but now I have an error saying "Expo Go has stopped working" with the options 'OK' and 'REPORT'. Clicking OK closes my app but dosen't close Expo Go. I coincidentally removed it from my phone and started a new project. Again, it was working at first, but now Expo Go throws the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem in 2 ways.

**First way**.

Remove Expo Go cache and try to restart the app.

**Second way**

If you are using wifi turn off wifi and  try to connect your desktop and mobile with mobile hotspot